# Did Sisko and Opaka's paths ever cross again?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine* season 1, episode 12 ("Battle Lines"), Kai Opaka tells Sisko:

> OPAKA: My work is here now, Commander. But your pagh and mine will cross again.

Sisko did have a vision of her later in the series, but did the writers (or novels) ever actually deliver on this statement? Did they in fact truly cross paths (or pagh) again?

Comment: Given that Sisko became a time-traveling demigod, it's certainly possible that their paths crossed *before* this event took place.

Comment: The *pagh* is essentially the Bajoran word for *soul,* right?  She might have meant this in the sense that they would meet again in the afterlife (if not sooner.) In a more spiritual sense, rather than in a prophetic sense.

Comment: @Steve-O That's possible, but honestly, I think this was the producers leaving things open-ended in case they thought of a good use for the character again...and then they never got around to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not on screen, and not so far in licensed stories. In Pocket's novels, Opaka did eventually return from the Gamma Quadrant (*Rising Son*, *Lesser Evil*, *Unity*), and Sisko has returned from the Prophets, but has chosen not to try to meet with Opaka as yet (*Rough Beasts of Empire*). [Source: ["Opaka Sulan" on Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Opaka_Sulan)]. Memory Alpha's page, which often notes production details, does not give any reason why the producers never tied off this loose end.

Comment: +1 just for reading the username "Shappe" in conjunction w/ a DS9 question. Allamaraine!

Comment: It's my actual name and everything :-) Imagine my surprise, first time I saw that episode...

Answer (score 2):

### Maybe yes, maybe no.

The Kai appears briefly in an "orb vision" in [DS9: Accession](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Accession_(episode)).

[image]

> Sisko keeps walking. The lights of the Promenade seem DIMMER now. The
> background hum of the station has dropped away. The feel is ominous...
> strange... he hears the RUSTLING again, whips around toward the
> source.
>
> No one.
>
> Disturbed, he turns to continue walking -- and finds himself
> face-to-face with...
>
> KAI OPAKA
>
> Sisko couldn't be more surprised.
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: Accession - Final Draft Screenplay](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/489.txt)</sup></sub>

According to Memory Alpha (referencing an anecdote from the [DS9 Companion](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine_Companion)), an earlier version of the draft script indicated that Sisko had concerns that it wasn't simply a vision but an attempt by the real Kai to contact him telepathically.

> *In ultimately unused dialogue from the second draft script of
> "Accession", Kira suggested to Sisko that the vision of Opaka he had
> seen was actually an attempt by Opaka to telepathically communicate
> with him. Skeptical of this theory, Sisko remarked, "We don't even
> know if she's still alive," which Kira then acknowledged.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Memory Alpha: Opaka](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Opaka#Disappearance)</sup></sub>

Comment: yeah - that was the only bit of info I found. The "if she is still alive" bit is odd though - considering the state in which they left her in "Battle Lines": basically immortal and trapped

Comment: @NKCampbell - I've not got my copy of the Companion to hand. I assume they've quoted near-verbatim

Comment: I was casting aspersions on the lack of memory of the writers of the draft script, not your accuracy :) - in other words, whoever had written that bit of dialogue could have remembered that is highly likely that Opaka was still alive. Apparently, that is why it was left unused.